# W32Time freezes Windows

Tags: windows-10, freeze, time

I have a Windows 10 tablet displaying some measurment data. It runs 24h a day. 
After some time it totally freezes. I found out that it has to do with the W32Time service.

When I connect to the tablet via psexec and run:

```
net stop w32time
```

Everything is normal, when I start w32time again, it hangs again.
I found out the w32time is non stop setting the clock to a fixed time. I enabled a debug log with w32tm.

Does anybody know what is causing this behavior?

Here is the log

```
151644 08:01:11.3518164s - Peer151644 08:01:11.3514248s151644     08:01:11.3515930s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
151644 08:01:11.3517243s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:13032961 SetUnsync: LI:3 S:0 RDl:0 RDs:0 TSF:0x0 
151644 08:01:11.3518042s - ClockDispln Discipline: Check and set secure time
151644 08:01:11.3518157s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
151644 08:01:11.3518840s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
151644 08:01:11.3518994s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
151644 08:01:11.3519677s - Setting the system time because it is outside the secure time limits.
151644 08:01:11.3519708s - PeerPollingThread: waiting 895.487s
151644 08:01:11.3520284s -  Current system time:  8:1:11.351 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3521121s -  Target system time:  8:1:11.352 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3514501s - ClockDispln Discipline: *SET*SECURE*TIME*
151644 08:01:11.3516121s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
151644 08:01:11.3517127s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:13032961 SetUnsync: LI:3 S:0 RDl:0 RDs:0 TSF:0x0 
151644 08:01:11.3517941s - ClockDispln Discipline: Check and set secure time
151644 08:01:11.3518133s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
151644 08:01:11.3518786s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
151644 08:01:11.3519155s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
151644 08:01:11.3519501s - Setting the system time because it is outside the secure time limits.
151644 08:01:11.3519777s - PeerPollingThread: waiting 895.487s
151644 08:01:11.3520092s -  Current system time:  8:1:11.351 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3520622s -  Target system time:  8:1:11.352 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3510976s - ClockDispln Discipline: *SET*SECURE*TIME*
151644 08:01:11.3512558s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
151644 08:01:11.3513971s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:13032961 SetUnsync: LI:3 S:0 RDl:0 RDs:0 TSF:0x0 
151644 08:01:11.3514731s - ClockDispln Discipline: Check and set secure time
151644 08:01:11.3514839s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
151644 08:01:11.3515530s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
151644 08:01:11.3516283s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
151644 08:01:11.3516375s - Setting the system time because it is outside the secure time limits.
151644 08:01:11.3516843s - PeerPollingThread: waiting 895.487s
151644 08:01:11.3517012s -  Current system time:  8:1:11.351 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3517519s -  Target system time:  8:1:11.352 3/10/2016
151644 08:01:11.3512112s - ClockDispln Discipline: *SET*SECURE*TIME*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on an Windows 10 machine. It seems, it is a Windows bug. Set the following Registry key to 0:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\SecureTimeLimits\SecureTimeConfidence
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to uninstall and reinstall the service using  w32tm /unregister then w32tm /register.

I've not had a system lock up from the time service, but I have had instances where the System doesn't really play well when the service has been gacked up. Uninstalling and reinstalling has resolved this.

Also, consider setting the service startup time Automatic Delayed. I'm not 100% sure why, but this tends to reduce a chance that it runs into a conflicting service etc...the time service will start a few minutes after the last service has started.